# Uppercase String Convert

Tags: php, string

I have strings from a source code and its like;

```
"REAL MADRİD - BARCELONA"
"VİLLAREAL - IDIONA"
"FENERBAHÇE - BEŞİKTAŞ IŞ"
etc.. etc.. etc..
```

**I want to convert this string totally lowercase and uppercase first character of each word.** (like ucwords). But i have a problem with **İI** and other utf-8 characters when using **ucwords** function.

I want exactly output for this strings like;

```
"Real Madrid - Barcelona"
"Villareal - Idıona"
"Fenerbahçe - Beşiktaş Iş"
```

What can i try?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found this functiom:

```
function mb_ucwords($str)
    {
        return mb_convert_case($str, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [ucwords](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) with [strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) php method combination

```
    $s = "REAL MADRID - BARCELONA";
    $s = ucwords(strtolower($s));

    #Real Madrid - Barcelona
```

[Check out this fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e529b9d42df6c37a43d6ffef6b1fc936944a644e)

For utf8 strings instead of **strtolower** you can use [mb_convert_case](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-case.php) method with **MB_CASE_TITLE** mode like:

```
    $s = "FENERBAHÇE - BEŞİKTAŞ IŞ";
    $s = mb_convert_case($s, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
```

[Check out this fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b852cd5c0ff7f4ecf769732f5ef1daf103b7a502)

please notice that the last one will work for sure also if the first letter of word is special utf8 kind

Comment: it's doesnt work at utf-8 characters like;
FENERBAHÇE - BEŞİKTAŞ IŞ

Comment: the last one is works, I'm using it right now but there is only problem with "I" and "İ" characters.

Comment: And what is the problem? To be honest I do not know `İ` character - isn't `i` lowercase for it?

Comment: Can you check this sample, http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/83db6ce3adfe0780f9b8720820a98cb0cf77da16

I writed comment line what a output, i want.
Thanks.

Comment: Do not use **MB_CASE_LOWER** first then everything is fine - [check out this](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/39909746d3c272b4469a7db596e040c8795cc064)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99404/discussion-between-kadir-cetintas-and-m-antkowicz).

Answer (score 0):

The function you need is `mb_strtolower()`

Usage: `echo mb_strtolower($str);`

For more details, read the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php).

Comment: I have a problem with utf-8 characters. Check this
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ea4829d356ca7e5b8351b69f25fb6fe1afc283bc

Comment: It could be a problem with the site. Did you check it locally or on your site?

Answer (score 0):

Need to use `strtolower` and `ucwords`

Example :

```
$string = "REAL MADRİD - BARCELONA";
$lower = strtolower($string); //first need to convert to lower string
$firstupper = ucwords($lower); //then change every word first letter is upper case
```

Comment: mb_strtolower instead strtolower

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$string = "REAL MADRID - BARCELONA";
$ans = ucwords(strtolower ( $string ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

echo ucwords(strtolower('Dhaka, JAMALPUR, sarishabari'));
```

Result is:

```
Dhaka, Jamalpur, Sarishabari
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you figured it out, you should use:

```
mb_strtolower
```

and

```
mb_convert_case
```

Here:

```
    $games = array(
    "REAL MADRİD - BARCELONA",
    "VİLLAREAL - IDIONA",
    "FENERBAHÇE - BEŞİKTAŞ IŞ",
    "İSTANBULSPOR A.Ş - FENERBAHÇE İŞ"
);

foreach($games as $game) {
    echo mb_convert_case($game, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8") . '<br>';
}
```

it will print the result you're looking for:

```
Real Madrid - Barcelona
Villareal - Idiona
Fenerbahçe - Beşiktaş Iş
İstanbulspor A.ş - Fenerbahçe İş
```

To capitalize like A.S a solution would be:

```
foreach($games as $game) {
    $tmp = str_replace(".",". ",$game);
    echo mb_convert_case($tmp, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8") . '<br>';
}
```

and you get:

```
Real Madrid - Barcelona
Villareal - Idiona
Fenerbahçe - Beşiktaş Iş
İstanbulspor A. Ş - Fenerbahçe İş
```

Of course, you may create your own function, especially if there are other requirements as well.

Comment: I have problems with I İ characters, Can you check this sample, http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/83db6ce3adfe0780f9b8720820a98cb0cf77da16

Comment: Ok, now I noticed the special 'I' character and I modified accordingly. It remains to address the issue with capitalizing the letter after '.' to get 'A.Ş'. You have to make a custom function for this, I would probably make something simple, like searching for '.' and replace it with '. ' (dot +space).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$string = "REAL MADRİD - BARCELONA";
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
$finalString =  mb_convert_case($string, MB_CASE_TITLE);
echo $finalString;
```

**Result:**

```
Real Madrid - Barcelona
```

Comment: did you checked? @kadir-Çetintaş

Comment: It has problem when "I" character converting to lowercase.
"I" to lowercase should be "ı" not "i"

Comment: it return valid characters @KadirÇetintaş